Java circular generic-type parameter issue
I have these interfaces and classes in a java (17) application:
public interface ISurvey<T extends ISurveyDetails<? extends ISurvey<T>>> {
    void setDetails(T details);
}

public interface ISurveyDetails<T extends ISurvey<? extends ISurveyDetails<T>>> {
    void setSurvey(T survey);
}

public class AppleSurvey implements ISurvey<AppleSurveyDetails> {
    @Override
    public void setDetails(AppleSurveyDetails details) {
    }
}

public class AppleSurveyDetails implements ISurveyDetails<AppleSurvey> {
    @Override
    public void setSurvey(AppleSurvey survey) {
    }
}

public class ComplexGenericUser {
    <T extends ISurveyDetails<ISurvey<T>>> void setDetail(ISurvey<T> survey, Supplier<T> detailMaker) {
        var detail = detailMaker.get();
        detail.setSurvey(survey);
        survey.setDetails(detail);
    }

    void useWithApple() {
        var appleSurvey = new AppleSurvey();
        setDetail(appleSurvey, AppleSurveyDetails::new);
    }
}

Whole system is ok except the call to setDetail() in useWithApple() method of ComplexGenericUser class. The compiler error states that no instance of type variable (T) exists so that AppleSurvey conforms to ISurvey<T>. How can I resolve this?

AppleSurveyDetails implements ISurveyDetails<AppleSurvey>. As written, your setDetail method expects AppleSurveyDetails to implement ISurveyDetails<ISurvey<AppleSurveyDetails>>, not ISurveyDetails<AppleSurvey>.
I think correctly parameterizing setDetail requires two type parameters, one for the survey and one for the details:
<D extends ISurveyDetails<S>, S extends ISurvey<D>>
void setDetail(S survey, Supplier<D> detailMaker) {
    var detail = detailMaker.get();
    detail.setSurvey(survey);
    survey.setDetails(detail);
}

You'll also need to fix your setDetail call - the supplier should just be AppleSurveyDetails::new, not () -> AppleSurveyDetails::new.

Wow! This seems nice!

Using full names for typevars is a really bad idea - it goes against java convention; folks reading that code will assume Survey is some sort of type. It should be D extends ISurveydetails<S>, S extends ISurvey<D>. Separately, having hungarian I all over the place is a bad idea, and having ref loops in your generics is.. also a bad idea. The question asker seems to have overdone it a bit here.

@rzwitserloot: Sure, changed the type parameters. I can't change the other stuff, of course.

@rzwitserloot Agree with the logic behind the java convention. But for this particular case, because of the verbosity of the explicit type parameters, I understood the solution readily (easier and quicker than the other answer which used T, U). I think .NET convention could be a bit helpful in these cases; i.e. say TDetail, TSurvey instead of T, U or Detail, Survey (adding a T before the type parameter, to indicate that it is a generic type parameter)

@rzwitserloot I am from .NET world, which is why there are the I prefix for the interfaces. Also, would you please suggest a solution without the ref-loop in the generics?

I think, the issue is in this part of your code
 <T extends ISurveyDetails<ISurvey<T>>> void setDetail(ISurvey<T> survey, Supplier<T> detailMaker) {
    var detail = detailMaker.get();
    detail.setSurvey(survey);
    survey.setDetails(detail);
}

the AppleSurvey doesn’t satisfy this because AppleSurveyDetails is not a direct subtype of ISurveyDetails<ISurvey<T>>.
To make it work maybe changing the signature of setDetail with something like:
 <T extends ISurveyDetails<U>, U extends ISurvey<T>> void setDetail(U survey, Supplier<T> detailMaker) {
     var detail = detailMaker.get();
     detail.setSurvey(survey);
     survey.setDetails(detail);     
}


This fails when I try compiling it.

Can you try <T extends ISurveyDetails, U extends ISurvey> void setDetail(U survey, Supplier detailMaker) {

That works (and is equivalent to my answer).

Well you need MORE GENERICS :)
Here is fixed code:
public interface ISurvey<S extends ISurvey<S, D>, D extends ISurveyDetails<S, D>> {
    void setDetails(D details);
}

public interface ISurveyDetails<S extends ISurvey<S, D>, D extends ISurveyDetails<S, D>> {
    void setSurvey(S survey);
}

public class AppleSurvey implements ISurvey<AppleSurvey, AppleSurveyDetails> {
    @Override
    public void setDetails(AppleSurveyDetails details) {
    }
}

public class AppleSurveyDetails implements ISurveyDetails<AppleSurvey, AppleSurveyDetails> {
    @Override
    public void setSurvey(AppleSurvey survey) {
    }
}

public class ComplexGenericUser {
    <S extends ISurvey< S, D>, D extends ISurveyDetails<S, D>> void setDetail(S survey, Supplier<D> detailMaker) {
        var detail = detailMaker.get();
        detail.setSurvey(survey);
        survey.setDetails(detail);
    }

    void useWithApple() {
        var appleSurvey = new AppleSurvey();
        setDetail(appleSurvey, AppleSurveyDetails::new);
    }
}


I don't think you actually need to add any parameters to ISurvey or ISurveyDetails. Adjusting the parameters on setDetail was enough in my tests.

Yep. It is enough to have 2  generic parameters on setDetail. I just started to add them and doesn't stopped at right moment,
